# SharePoint Online Search Display Templates are not reflecting the changes made

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I am working on custom item template. However, when I made changes in template, this didn’t seem to reflect my changes…

Using the debugger of chrome, I saw the old version of the js files were still used for the item templates. Somehow these where cached…

If I clear my browser cache, then it's working fine. But I don't want to clear my cache or do a hard refresh after every changes done in item template…

Need suggestion to fix this…

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to clear browser cache, you could change the name of the js file such as filename_v1 which you use for the item template.

Comment: for the item template or display template, js file is automatically created with the name of item template or display template.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the cache while developing.

In IE it's called "always refresh from server" and can be found using developer tools (F12).

[image]

For Chrome it's simply called "disable cache":[image] (also in developer tools)

Comment: this is happening on Production, I can't tell my users to disable cache.

Comment: Interesting. Never had that "in production". Are you using BLOB cache or page output cache in the farm?